# python conditional check in text

Tags: python, loops, input

I am writing a python with text, the output is all strings, i have not uploaded any library and i am trying to have this condition with in my text

```
f.write("G3")
f.write(" ")
i = raw_input("enter the G3 for wind J or K =  ")
for i:
   if i=J
    f.write(i)
    f.write(" ")
    f.write("CDS1")
    a = raw_input("alter the CDS1  =  ")
    f.write(a)
    f.write(" ")
    f.write("DELTA")
    d = raw_input("alter the DELTA  = ")
    f.write(d)
    f.write(" ")
    f.write("AGROW")
    f.write("\n")
   else i = K
   f.write(i)
   f.write(" ")
   f.write("A")
   f.write("\n")
   f.write("WCAP K")
   f.write("\n")
```

I get this

```
for i:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

have i written it correctly or am i missing something ?

Comment: I think that you need to have a look to the for loop syntax: https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html#for

Comment: writing a python with text?

Comment: @salmanwahed yes, it basically is to be incorporated in a larger script for automation, it is possible and if you have large files it save you the trouble of writing code from scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you wanted to do something like:

```
for letter in i:
```

Also you need to compare against the string literals 'J' and 'K':

```
if letter == 'J':
    # do first stuff
elif letter == 'K':
    # do other stuff
```

Also note that *comparison* is with `==`, *assignment* is with `=`. You have this incorrect in your `if` blocks.

Also, indentation is **very important** in Python, make sure your tabs (or spaces) are aligned properly.

Comment: thank you about the == notice, i totally overlooked it, on I took your advice and it overcame my trouble but if i have multiple if can i use something else that elif?

Comment: You can do `if letter == 'J' or letter == 'K' or letter == 'M'` etc.